# How to run perl script with multiple args from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl, subprocess, python-os

I made a python code that must sequentially execute a series of perl commands on the PC shell, the problem is that I did not realize that to send these scripts I have to add parameters (i have n_params), advice?

example command to send
**perl [file_name.pl] [params]**

To run these commands on the windows CMD I am using os and subprocess

python code example

```
# command = perl [file_name.pl] [params]
# path = location/of/where/the/pl/file/is/saved

perl_script = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe",path + command], stdout=sys.stdout)
perl_script.communicate()
```

But running the script like this, the code gets me wrong because it says it can't find the filename in the specific directory

Comment: `["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", path + command]` does not look correct. I think it should be `["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", path+"file_name.pl", "param1", "param2", ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This argument to `Popen()`

```
["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", path + command]
```

does not look correct since you wrote that `command` is `perl [file_name.pl] [params]`. Instead try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe", path+"file_name.pl", "param1", "param2", ...])
```